# C# OnAdd / OnRemove / OnModified event for List<T>.<some action>(objT)

Tags: c#, .net, events, c#-4.0

I have a property, say `MyList`, that's of Type `List<int>`.

In the `set` clause of the property some other logic is executed.

I'd like to execute the same logic when the List is modified.

```cs
public class MyType
{
    public List<int> MyList
    {
        get { return _MyList; }
        set
        {
            listUpdate(); 
            _MyList = value; 
        }
    }
    private List<int> _MyList

    private void listUpdate()
    {
        // Do something... 
    }
}
```

I know I could create my own class that inherited from `List<T>` and override all of the methods that modify the `List` but wondered if anyone had a better idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, I have a better idea. Use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).
It has been created exactly for your purpose. The event you want to subscribe to is `CollectionChanged`. It is called for all changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which gives notification of modifications:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easly with `ObservableCollection`. It has also special constructor for `List`:

```
public ObservableCollection(
      List<T> collection
)
```

You can read about it there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202.aspx